# AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with gi certificates

Tags: php, web-services, laravel, web, laravel-5

i am using this package

```
https://github.com/Vinelab/cdn
```

for laravel CDN asset management
after configring all the package when i execute this command to push assets to s3 bucket

```
php artisan cdn:push
```

its show me error

> \Exception\S3Exception] executing "ListObjects" on
>   "https://s3.eu-central1.amazonaws.com/moberries-assets?encode=url";
>   AWS HTTP error: cURL error 60: Peer certificate cannot be
>   authenticated with gi certificates
>
> Http\Exception\RequestException] ror 60: Peer certificate cannot be
>   authenticated with given CA certificates
>
> Http\Ring\Exception\RingException] ror 60: Peer certificate cannot be
>   authenticated with given CA certificates

i vitist the followign links for this issue and also include the cancert certificate in the project file.

when i run the command it always shown the above mentioned error

i consult the following links

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/issues/39://)

Please if one has its solution for laravel project then reply fast.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occur because the package not load the cacert.pen certificate file from their config/cdn.php while connecting to the server so, server always reject the request and give authentication error

**solution:**

Add cacert.pen certificate file in public directory of your project

And add the following code to AwsS3Provider.php package file

File path is

\xampp\htdocs\yourproject\vendor\vinelab\cdn\src\Vinelab\Cdn\Providers\AwsS3Provider.php on line 161 below the region code

```
'http' => ['verify' => public_path().'/cacert.pem',],
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this similar issue after update my project library. Finally, **Kashif Ali** answer gives me some clue.

But I could not find where to put cacert.pem file.

After I update this below setting to **config/fileSystem.php**, it's solved my problem.

```
's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('S3_KEY','your key'),
            'secret' => env('S3_SECRET','your secret'),
            'region' => env('S3_REGION','your region'),
            'bucket' => env('S3_BUCKET',"bucket name"),
            'http'       => ['verify'=> public_path('cacert.pem')]
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

Add cacert.pem to your project public directory and add complete path here like
'http'       => ['verify'=> 'D:myProjectDirectory/cacert.pem')]